# Cron not working with minutes

Tags: java, spring, cron

(Update: apparently there are no seconds in cron jobs. However, my question now becomes: what explains the cron behaving this way? Thank you)

I have two cron triggers, one is supposed to come in just moments before the other one.

First I had **task 1** come in every 59 seconds

```
*/59 * * * * ?
```

And **task 2** come in every 59 seconds, but offset by 15 seconds.

```
15/59 * * * * ?
```

This worked fine. No complaints. Now I want to just move this values over to the minutes column. This time, there is only a minute offset, which is negligible since the task repeats every 59 minutes.

**Task 1**

```
* */59 * * * ?
```

**Task 2**

```
* 1/59 * * * ?
```

Suddenly, **task 1** is constantly firing and **task 2** doesn't fire at all. The change described above seems to be the only thing affecting this.

Comment: To be more specific, Task 1 clears all entries of a column in a database to 0. Task two selects a random row and changes that row's column to 1. So every hour the "1" moves from row to row while all others go back to zero.

Comment: You tagged the question with Spring: are you talking about real corn or Springs `@Schedule` annotation. The difference is important spring has seconds, cron not!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`* */59 * * *` means run every minute (the first * is minutes) in the current hour, and then wait 59 hours to run again.

`* 1/59 * * *` means run every minute in the first hour (which you are not in, hence task 2 never fires) and then run every minute in the hour 50 hours later.

I think the problem is still the seconds/minutes confusion.

**EDIT**: Note some versions of Cron will not accept a number preceding a '/'... it must be a range.  So for your use case I would use `*/59 * * * *` and `1-59/59 * * * *`

Comment: I see. Yes, I had always thought the first * was minutes, I only assumed it was seconds because of its behavior.

Comment: Anyway, I also read that */5 * * * * is a shorthand for "run every 5 mins" how would you do that for hours, say every three hours, * */3 * * *, right?

Comment: @ajko right, */3 is every 3 hours.  Scroll down to "Cron Expression" here for a good read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Just saw your edit. So that would do once every 59 minutes, correct? I'll give that a spin. Thank you.

Comment: Wikipedia to the rescue. Okay, so in your example, the * in */59 means for every minute value (1-59), execute. Then the 59 means wait 59 minutes during this time to repeat this again?

Comment: @ajko yup, except */59 means 0-59 inclusive (not 1-59).

Comment: I wasn't sure why mine was still running every hour and it was because I was using a number instead of a *. Thanks for the additional tip there.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are no *seconds*

```
*    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
│    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Yes, I was confused about that as well, but it was in fact firing at 59 seconds when I had it in what everyone told me was the minutes column. I figured the ? had something to do with it.

Comment: But assuming this is no exception to the standard cron format, what would explain it behaving the way it does? (Thanks for your help.)

Comment: */59 would expand to 0-59/59 ... which would be every minute after rounding I suspect. I challenge you to get cron to run your process more than once a minute :)

Comment: No I take your word for it, there are even posts where people ask how to make their cron run every 20 seconds (why?) and of course, everyone says there are no seconds. I only ask because it is behaving that way :)